# converting column with multiple datatypes pandas to character

Tags: python, pandas

I read in a csv file and I have col1 having multiple data types.
Col1 is apparently of type int64, but the values are shown below and they are not integers..

```
col1
1.0
1
NaN
0.0
0
2+
```

When I do `df['col1'].astype(int)` i get an error: cannot convert float NaN to integer...but this shouldn't work anyway. I want to make all the floats to be integers and than convert to characters..

Expected output should be

```
col1
1
1
NaN
0
0
2+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['col1'].astype(stype = int, errors = 'ignore')
```

Comment: the type is a float64 and not an int64

Comment: But you wrote: "I want to make all the floats to be integers". My code above will do this conversion